# Mesh has invisible parts after exporting

Tags: mesh, export

This is my mesh in Blender:

[image]

And this my mesh when placed in UDK:

[image]

As you can see it doesn't have the human head/chest part, parts of the hood are invisible, and it has some white lines. Why?

Comment: It looks like the normals of the human are inverted, try selecting all in edit mode and pressing Ctrl+N

Comment: It worked , but i still have those other bugs and as u can see it's like the part where the hood connects to the cloth dissappears when u look it on some directions , why ?

Comment: That is because the mesh has no thickness. Try adding some thickness to the mesh. The fastest way is probably the [solidify modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Solidify).

Comment: Cool , but i still have those white lines and why is my model a "non-collision" model ?

Comment: I don't know, that sounds like something to do with UDK.

Comment: And the white lines ?

Comment: It looks like some sort of shader that is being used by UDK.

Comment: @gandalf3 - thickness shouldn't have anything todo with the normals (except for the boundaries), there are obvious issues across the surface that wouldnt be fixed by solidify.

Comment: @ideasman42 I suggested solidify to fix the "disappearing hood".

Comment: And it worked , the strange lines where because it wasnt UV unraped

Answer (score 2):

It looks like:

- The human mesh's normals are flipped. You can correct that by selecting all of it in edit mode (<kbd>A</kbd>) and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>
- The hood/robe mesh has no thickness, so parts of it will disappear due to [*backface culling*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling). You can fix this by adding some thickness with the [*Solidify modifier*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html).