# Graphics are broken

Tags: modeling

So i'm making a game and so i'm just making all my 3d models for it and the boat that i making is for some reason see though in my game engine (unity 3D) and when like the inside of the model is see through but the outside seems to be good,so is their any[image] way that can make the inside not see though i was hoping if anyone knew a way around this.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6651/599

Comment: @gandalf3 this makes it do the complete opposite i can see the inside but not the outside i need it to render both

Comment: Yes, for that you'll want to give your mesh some thickness. Right now it's essentially a 2D surface (like infinitely thin paper or something), something that's quite impossible in the real world. See point two in my answer to that question

Comment: @gandalf3 THANKS one last question can i make a comment a answer

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean..? Do you want to [accept](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) a comment? If so, that isn't possible, and I can no longer add answers to this question now that I've marked it as a duplicate. I'm glad you got it sorted out though :)

Comment: @gandalf3 ok but thanks for helping :)